# Meaning of the suffix -weilig

Tags: meaning, suffix

Does the suffix *-weilig* have a particular meaning?

I've seen it in a few words, such as *langweilig*, *zeitweilig* etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The german noun *Weile* is cognate to *while* and means "while"<sup>[Noun]</sup>, "spell"<sup>[period of time]</sup> "duration", "span of time". Adding the suffix *-ig* is a way to create an adjective from a noun.

The verb *weilen* means "to rest", "to stay at one place (for a while)".

Hence, the suffix *-weilig* means as much as "during", "while"<sup>[Adjective]</sup>, "in the time of". But it is not always possible to guess the meaning, since it has changed over time or has focussed on a particular idea which is only loosely related to the notion of *Weile*:

- *langweilig* literally translates to something like "long-during, long lasting". It came to mean "boring" as figurative speech.
- *kurzweilig*, the opposite to *langweilig*, "diverting", "amusing"
- *derweilig*, more common now as *derweilen*: "in the meantime"
- *jeweilig*, more common now as *jeweils*: "each", "at a time"
- *zeitweilig*: literally translates to "during a certain time", meaning "temporary", "intermittant",
- *einstweilig*: literally translates to "once-whiley", "at a certain time", is used primarily in the legal term *einstweilige Verfügung*: "injunction" and means "provisional", "interlocutory".

However, as [Schmuddi](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/22043/schmuddi) points out in a comment, all examples containing -weilig are lexicalized words with opaque, non-compositional meaning and *-weilig* is not a productive morpheme of German anymore, you could not use it to form a new word anymore.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118642/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathan-scholbach-meaning-of-the-suffix-weilig).

Comment: I thought the discussion was pertinent and even affected your post.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Moving the discussion to the chat does not contain or even imply a claim that it was irrelevant. Please keep on discussing in the linked chat-room. Also, see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/warum-werden-diskussionen-in-den-chat-verschoben-why-do-discussions-get-moved

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach it just sweeps it in a corner away from people who might *find* it relevant. It is, as it has ever and always been, useless and destructive.

Comment: @hobbs This discussion should not be held under a post, but on meta. Please discuss under the link I've shared above.

Comment: @hobbs: On math.se people will often take a discussion into a chat room and someone will "report back" brief and pertinent details, either in a single comment or by updating the answer. It works well.